How to disable the upload from mobile feature on Edge
My selenium automation breaks with new Edge "experimental mode" - "DOWNLOAD MICROSOFT EDGE MOBILE APP" POP-UP
 EdgeOptions edgeoptions = new EdgeOptions();
 edgeoptions.AddArgument("--disable-features=msEdgeEnableNurturingFramework");
       
 driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeoptions);

I tried the above, and it still popup opens and automation breaks.
I also saw this code which I added but
edgeoptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", { "user_experience_metrics": { "personalization_data_consent_enabled": True} });
edgeoptions does not contain a definition for add_experimental_option
Any help would be appreciated.

Here are two ways for your reference:
This code
edgeoptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"user_experience_metrics": {"personalization_data_consent_enabled": True}})

is a Python code. You can try to convert it into C# code to try whether it works.
The following is the C# code I converted:
edgeoptions.AddUserProfilePreference("user_experience_metrics", new
  {
     personalization_data_consent_enabled = true
  });

If the first method does not work, you can try to add the following code to see if it can work.
edgeoptions.AddArgument("--disable-features=msDownloadsUseUploadButton");


Thanks for your help. I tried both ways and it didn't work.  still the popup opens up. Not sure how to resolve this issue

I searched the relevant code of using Selenium to avoid the DOWNLOAD MICROSOFT EDGE Mobile App "Menu, but I did not find some useful codes, so I did n’t have more suggestions about using Selenium Automation to close this menu.
But I can provide you with another alternative. You can close the MENU by disabling "ShowRecommendationsEnabled" Policy. You can refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#showrecommendationsenabled

I don't think that solution works for me. My company doesn't allow individuals to change the registry settings. Even if i could changed, my automation will run on EC2 or on prem machines which I have no control over. Thanks for taking time in researching this issue for me. For now I am going to run my automation on Chrome rather than Edge.
